# List of French Hospitals and Health Clinics

Tags: data-request, medical, france

List of French Hospitals and Health Clinics

There might not be a database covering all french hospital. 
So if we need more data that OpenStreetMap ha - Below is the data for France.
The French government has created a website showing the list of all 4307 hospitals and clinics in France:

http://www.ScopeSante.fr

Click on "*Voir la liste des établissements*" to get the full list.

[image: hopitaux]

You will need to scrape that. Each hospital name has a link to [its detailed information page](http://www.scopesante.fr/fiches-detaillees/750150146/):

[image: hopital]

I have just sent them a message asking for a dump of the data. They replied to me saying that all of their data comes from the FINESS database, which is also maintained by the French government, and available online "*for private use*" and unfortunately does not have dump downloads, so that would mean scraping that:

[image: FINESS]

what is aimed; i want to have a full list of the dataset.

See the https://ws.scopesante.fr/v4/carte-etablissements

The private API returns the full list of establishments along with their "id" numbers in JSON format.This is a great approach; This is the full list. We can use the "id" number of each organization to look up the "details" page for each organization. So, using the route to the "details" page: https://www.scopesante.fr#/etablissements/PUT_ID_NUMBER_HERE/fiche-detaillee/

We can get the details for a specific establishment directly by calling the API. See:
https://ws.scopesante.fr/v4/fiche-identite/010000024

This returns the details on the specific establishment.
We can replace the number on the end of the URL with the "id" number of the establishment you are looking up. Using an API is usually more efficient than scraping the pages directly.

We have for example the follwing ending of a URL

010000024

This number is also visible in the overview see the https://ws.scopesante.fr/v4/carte-etablissements

So I have to do some combination:

**The question is** - how to retrieve the full dataset of the approx 4000 records ?

I guess that the key is

a. retrival

b. processing of JSON-data and

c. creating a db that stores the whole dataset

Now I want to have a closer look at the decoding with `json_decode()` -  as with every JSON API.

Many thanks for your help here.

Comment: [FINESS Extraction du Fichier des établissements](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/finess-extraction-du-fichier-des-etablissements/#_)

Comment: *Now I want to have a closer look at the decoding with json_decode() - as with every JSON API.* If you have specific problems with it, that is a programming question, which belongs on [SO]