# Is there a database of medical clinics, hospitals, etc. and when and where they were established?

Tags: data-request, medical, business

I'm looking for data on every type of medical clinic, including hospitals, urgent care clinics, doctors' offices, etc. There are several other questions that are similar, e.g. [this one](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4833/3565) and [this one](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/12476/3565), but those deal with Europe. Furthermore, although data sources like Google Maps and Open Street Maps will include the location/coordinates, they don't include information on **when** the clinic/hospital was established. **These dates are essential for my analysis.**